# The `repeat` syntax of gradual typed lambda calculus defined by Racket?

Tags: algorithm, syntax, functional-programming, typed-lambda-calculus

I don't understand what's the meaning of `repeat (j l h)` in the following code snippet from a paper about gradual typed lambda calculus, the algorithm is quicksort, maybe the syntax definition can be guessed by someone who know the algorithm:

[image]

---

**Edit**: From my current understanding, the algorithm has error, it should be: `[i: (Ref Int) (box (- l 1))]`, i.e. `h` should be `l`.

---

link to the paper: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3314221.3314627#sec-supp

The source code of their Grift compiler is written in `.rkt` so I hope if someone know about Racket can help, the repeat syntax is defined here: https://github.com/Gradual-Typing/Grift/blob/95c56d94b38e9b33adf7a662c6d7768430d977da/src/language/syntax.rkt#L126
[image]

I'm new to functional programming/Racket/GTLC+, sorry I've tried my best to describe my question...

Answer (score 0):

1. The meaning of `repeat(j l h)` is `for j in a[l]...a[h]`(inclusive).
2. The meaning of `[i: Int (box (- h 1))]` initialize  a `Int` variable named `i` create at heap with value `operator-(h, 1)`.
3. The algorithm has error on the line: `[i: (Ref Int) (box (- h 1))]`, I think it should be `[i: (Ref Int) (box (- l 1))]`, reason: I consider `h` as high-end and the `repeat` loop will increment `i` when condition is met, this may result in `i > h` which is absurd.